# Rails. using a web socket like rest, but with an open connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, websocket

I have a web api that posts json to different external endpoints on certain conditions.  We have a new client that wants us to open a web socket connection with them during an event, send them the data (json) when we get it via this socket, and close the socket after the event.  I'm having a hard time figuring out the rails way to do this.

How do I open a web socket connection and keep it open? (basically where would the client sit/ what would the definition look like).

How do I send messages over the socket from a controller? (eg. after processing a post request send new data to this websocket)

How do I close the connection?

Comment: What rails are you on? rails 5? You can use the ActionCable for implementing websockets

Comment: @pibano, I think OP is asking about becoming a WebSocket client (rather than server).

Comment: If that's the case OP can use javascript [WebSocket](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket#Example)

Comment: @pibano -Myst Yes, I need to be the client, I need to send data over a web socket from a rails controller.  For example, when a post comes in (from the UI) the last step in the controller method (which is in ruby)is  sending the json object over a web socket to someone else.  I don't care about the response, it just needs to maintain a connection until I tell it to close.

Comment: So you want to create a websocket connection in your controller? Also having the ability to close the connection?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this gem called [Faye](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby). Here's an example for connecting and sending data: (note: I didn't test it)

```
# Open the connection
ws = Faye::WebSocket::Client.new('ws://www.example.com/')

# Send data to connection
ws.send(YOURJSONDATA)

# Close connection (RFC 6455)
ws.close
```

Notes for faye:

- [Using the WebSocket client](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#using-the-websocket-client)
- [Adding headers and other options to connection](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#initialization-options)
- [WebSocket API](https://github.com/faye/faye-websocket-ruby#websocket-api)

[RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would really recommend using `iodine` over `Faye`. Not only does iodine support pub/sub out of the box (and an optional Redis bridge/engine), but it's part of the HTTP server (instead of running an external event loop and IO management module)... then again, I'm biased.